# Count fired rules without modifying existing rules

Tags: clips

How can you count how many rules were fired during the execution of a program in CLIPS? But I don't want to modify the existing rules, like adding a counter inside each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the (watch statistics) command:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (defrule rule-1 (data ?) =>)
CLIPS> (assert (data 1) (data 2) (data 3))
<Fact-3>
CLIPS> (watch statistics)
CLIPS> (run)
3 rules fired        Run time is 1.60000054165721e-05 seconds.
187499.936524567 rules per second.
4 mean number of facts (4 maximum).
1 mean number of instances (1 maximum).
2 mean number of activations (3 maximum).
CLIPS>
```